# How can I drive a bridge with three states and two high-side switches?

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, boost, gate-driving, full-bridge

I want to drive a configuration similar to the one presented in Figure 1 of [A novel tri-state boost converter with fast dynamics](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1035142/), but use a MOSFET instead of the diode for efficiency.

[image]

I want to put two in bridge, but the exact circuit is not important. Key features are that each side will have 3 switches, of which 2 are high-sides switches. Each side has 3 states, with dead time between states. Diodes are not an option for efficiency reasons.

So the question is how I can drive a PWM with 3 states with dead time, something like this:

[image]

Bridge driver IC only have 2 or 4 switches with two states.
So probably separate high-side and low-side gate drivers will be required.
But that leaves the problem of dead time.
Are there any PWM IC or MCU with PWM that can handle dead time between three states?

Comment: the document that you referred to is not accessible without a login .... please provide a full circuit

Comment: I added the figure from the paper, as well as a wave form of the desired PWM signal. It's not about the circuit, it's about finding chips that can drive 3 switches.